# Multiplying or adding Probabilities

Tags: probability

In a game if the spinner lands on a bonus on the game wheel(four segments: Red, Blue, Green and Bonus), the person must then predict what segment the spinner will land on next. If it lands there the person wins the bonus.
What is the probability?
I calculated it like this:
1/4(probability of landing on bonus) * 1/4(probability of landing on predicted segment) = 1/16
I'm not sure whether I should be adding the probabilities, I multiplied because I reasoned that it's an AND case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. You need to know $P(A \land B)$, and when $A$ and $B$ are independent (which they are in this case), then

$$P(A \land B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$$

Adding probabilities is for when you are looking dor the probability of one of several *mutually exclusive* events to happen. For example, the probability for the spinner to land on either Red *or* Green would be $P(R \lor G)= P(R) +P(G)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$