# Adding or multiplying probability

Tags: probability

In spite of the titles, this is not a duplicate of [Multiplying or adding Probabilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449528/multiplying-or-adding-probabilities)

If an inefficient mask is 38% protection **against** viral transmission, then it gives a 62% probability of **passing** the infection.  If both parties are both wearing them, the protection is improved.  My last math class was fifty years ago, but I believe the way to do this is 62% × 62% = 38.44% or 61.56% protection.  Makes sense that two barriers are better than one.

But how much protection for an umasked person confronted by two masked persons.  Seems to me his risk is increased, but there will still be some protection.  Adding risks doesn't work, though.  If I say he has 62% of being infected by one, and 62$ chance of being infected by the other, and (24?)% of being infected by both, then his risk is 148% which makes no sense.

Given two events with an X percent chance of Y, what is the best way to determine the chance that one or both will be Y?

Comment: I'd say the unmasked person has a $62\%$ chance of being infected by the first person, a $62\%$ chance of being infected by the second person, a $62\%\times62\%=38.44\%$ chance of being infected by both; overall, a $(62+62-38.44)\%=85.56\%$ chance of being infected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the event's complements:

The probability the unmasked person is not infected by either is the probability the mask is effective in the first encounter AND is effective in the second encounter. Since these are independent probabilities, we can multiply to see the probability the unmasked person is not infected is $(0.38)^2$. So the probability the unmasked person is infected by either is $1-(0.38)^2 = .8556$